# Prevent Web Pages From Maintaining Page Scroll Position On Reload

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I prevent Web Pages From Maintaining Page Scroll Position On Reload

Comment: it dosent really say it all, since at my system, it does not maintain scroll position on reload. can you elaborate on what you do, what the page contains, is there an anchor tag etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call window.scrollTo(xpos,ypos) javascript function on page load. More can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp)

Call this function when the page is fully loaded. You can use jQuery to make sure the function is called once page is completely loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  window.scrollTo(0,0);    
});
```

Working example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kNpyv/)

Comment: <body onload="scrollTo(0,0)"> doesn't do it. Why not?

Comment: window.scrollTo(0,0); Looks like your missing window.

Comment: Still not working. Places that at bottom of my js file. Nothing. Tried removing all other js, css, etc.

Comment: scrollTo is working fine in demo for which i have provided the link in answer. There might be some conflicts in your code, give it a try in some other browser.

Comment: I setup a test page. 1 js file, 1 css files, all connected to an index page. The css says the body is 1000px high. That works. I can scroll down a blank page. I put an alert in the .js file to make sure it works. It does. I add you code form above. I'm in safari. I refresh the page, I'm still scrolled down.

Why does it only work in your example???

Comment: This is driving me crazy, please take a look.